# Difference between contravariant and covariant vector multiplication

Tags: metric-tensor, relativity, tensor-calculus, notation, covariance

I am having trouble in distinguishing the difference between two types of multiplication. Basically if we have $X^{\mu}=(ct,\textbf{x})^{\mu}$, what is the difference between

$$\textbf{j}_{\mu}~X^{\mu}$$

and

$$\textbf{j}^{\mu}~X^{\mu} $$

where $\textbf{j}$ is the four-current.

Comment: The first (upper and lower indices contracted) is invariant under Lorentz transformation. The second one is a thing that transform in a complicated way under Lorentz transformation. Where have you seen such a product?

Answer (score 1):

If you work with Einstein summation notation,
the first one, $j_\mu X^\mu$ , is actually the scalar product of these two 4-vectors. This scalar product works with the helps of the metric tensor $\eta_{\mu \nu}$ in the following way
\begin{align}
j_\mu X^\mu = j^\mu X_\mu = j^\mu \eta_{\mu \nu} X^\nu \, .
\end{align}
The metric tensor tells you how distances in spacetime are measured. In standard Minkowski space ,this is $(\eta_{\mu \nu}) = diag(1,-1,-1,-1)$.

(Note that Minskowski metric only holds for flat spacetimes. Curved spacetimes of general relativity are described by different metric tensors, in fact, Einstein's field equations are differential equations for metric tensors.)

So you can see from the equation above, that co- and contravariant vectors are related by the metric tensor as
\begin{align}
X_\mu = \eta_{\mu \nu} X^\nu \, .
\end{align}
This is the reason why it is often said that
\begin{align}
x^\mu = \begin{pmatrix} ct \\ \vec{x} \end{pmatrix} \, , x_\mu = \begin{pmatrix} ct \\ -\vec{x} \end{pmatrix} \, ,
\end{align}
which is a little sloppy in notation. Think of them as vectors and covectors.

The object $j^\mu X^\mu$, on the other hand, is not a sum but only a product of components depending on the value of $\mu$, since Einstein summation only sums if there are "the same indices bottom and top".

Comment: Thank you! Could you please explain further what you mean by "a product of components depending on the value of $\mu$"?

Comment: These are open lorentz indices, so this term per se is dependent on the choice of the value $\mu$. Say $\mu=0 \Rightarrow j^\mu X^\mu = j^0 X^0 $. Terms which have an open index (not contracted), are not invariant under lorentz transformation . The behaviour under lorentz transformation is then dependent on the structure of the term with open indices.